# Anyone used the Silverlight datagrid?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

We're thinking of building a major project around the Silverlight datagrid.

If any has any stories, comments or opinions on their persona experience of developing with the Silverlight datagrid, then I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Galloway is a great resource on Silverlight.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/